# cuda dot product of two vectors not working for N>=369

Tags: cuda, dot-product

I have implemented a vector dot product as below.
It is compiled with CUDA 7.5 with `compute_20,sm_20` and `const int THREADS_PER_BLOCK = 16;`.

This is happening for both floats and doubles.

It works upto `n=368`, but beyond that, the result is incorrect. I was wondering whether the problem is with my implementation code or with the values that I am using (please see second code, initialisations) e.g. may be the addition beyond `n=368` introduces floating point errors (this may be odd as the same error is happening for both float and doubles).

```
int divUp(int total, int grain) { return (total+grain-1)/grain; }

__device__ __forceinline__ double atomicAdd(double* address, double val)
{
    unsigned long long int* address_as_ull = (unsigned long long int*)address;
    unsigned long long int old = *address_as_ull, assumed;
    do
    {
        assumed = old;
        old = atomicCAS(address_as_ull, assumed, __double_as_longlong(val+__longlong_as_double(assumed)));
    }
    while(assumed!=old);
    return __longlong_as_double(old);
}

__device__ __forceinline__ float atomicAdd(float* address, float val)
{
    unsigned int *ptr = (unsigned int *)address;
    unsigned int old, newint, ret = *ptr;
    do {
        old = ret;
        newint = __float_as_int(__int_as_float(old)+val);
    } while((ret = atomicCAS(ptr, old, newint)) != old);

    return __int_as_float(ret);
}

template<typename T>
__global__ void vecdotk(const T* a, const T* b, const int n, T* c)
{
    __shared__ T temp[THREADS_PER_BLOCK];
    int x = threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    if(x==0) c[0] = 0.0;
    if(x<n) {temp[threadIdx.x] = a[x]*b[x];
    }
    else temp[threadIdx.x] = 0.0;
    __syncthreads();

    if(0==threadIdx.x)
    {
        T sum = 0.0;
        for(int j=0; j<THREADS_PER_BLOCK; ++j)
        {
            sum += temp[j];
        }
        atomicAdd(c, sum);
    }
}

template<typename T>
void dot(const T* a, const T* b, const int n, T* c)
{
    dim3 block(THREADS_PER_BLOCK);
    dim3 grid(divUp(n, block.x), 1);
    vecdotk<T><<<grid, block>>>(a, b, n, c);
    cudaSafeCall(cudaGetLastError());
};
```

I use the following two host vectors to fill the input device arrays (which currently I have not shown as they are a part of a bigger library). Basically I want to compute the sum of square series i.e.

[image: equation]

```
// fill host vectors a and b
for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
{
    h_vec_a[i] = i+1;//__mat_rand();
    h_vec_b[i] = i+1;//__mat_rand();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't work:

```
if(x==0) c[0] = 0.0;
```

There is no guarantee (in CUDA) that thread 0 runs first or that this line will run before other threads get to any point in the code. You'll need to initialize `c[0]` before launching this kernel. Otherwise, some threads may do their atomic add to c, and then, sometime later, thread 0 may initialize c[0] to zero.

Also, CUDA already provides a `float` version of atomicAdd, there is no reason for you to provide your own. And, running threadblocks of 16 threads will not give you good performance (I would recommend just using the CUBLAS dot product function.) With the fix for `c[0]` (remove that line of code, and initialize `c[0]` before the kernel) your code runs correctly for me:

```
$ cat t372.cu
#include <stdio.h>

const int n = 2048;
#ifdef USE_DOUBLE
typedef double mytype;
#else
typedef float mytype;
#endif
const int THREADS_PER_BLOCK = 16;

int divUp(int total, int grain) { return (total+grain-1)/grain; }
#if 0
__device__ __forceinline__ double atomicAdd(double* address, double val)
{
    unsigned long long int* address_as_ull = (unsigned long long int*)address;
    unsigned long long int old = *address_as_ull, assumed;
    do
    {
        assumed = old;
        old = atomicCAS(address_as_ull, assumed, __double_as_longlong(val+__longlong_as_double(assumed)));
    }
    while(assumed!=old);
    return __longlong_as_double(old);
}

__device__ __forceinline__ float atomicAdd(float* address, float val)
{
    unsigned int *ptr = (unsigned int *)address;
    unsigned int old, newint, ret = *ptr;
    do {
        old = ret;
        newint = __float_as_int(__int_as_float(old)+val);
    } while((ret = atomicCAS(ptr, old, newint)) != old);

    return __int_as_float(ret);
}
#endif
template<typename T>
__global__ void vecdotk(const T* a, const T* b, const int n, T* c)
{
    __shared__ T temp[THREADS_PER_BLOCK];
    int x = threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    //if(x==0) c[0] = 0.0;
    if(x<n) {temp[threadIdx.x] = a[x]*b[x];
    }
    else temp[threadIdx.x] = 0.0;
    __syncthreads();

    if(0==threadIdx.x)
    {
        T sum = 0.0;
        for(int j=0; j<THREADS_PER_BLOCK; ++j)
        {
            sum += temp[j];
        }
        atomicAdd(c, sum);
    }
}

template<typename T>
cudaError_t dot(const T* a, const T* b, const int n, T* c)
{
    dim3 block(THREADS_PER_BLOCK);
    dim3 grid(divUp(n, block.x), 1);
    vecdotk<T><<<grid, block>>>(a, b, n, c);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return cudaGetLastError();
};

int main(){

  mytype *h_vec_a, *h_vec_b, *d_vec_a, *d_vec_b, *h_c, *d_c;
  int bs = n*sizeof(mytype);
  h_vec_a = (mytype *)malloc(bs);
  h_vec_b = (mytype *)malloc(bs);
  h_c = (mytype *)malloc(sizeof(mytype));
  cudaMalloc(&d_vec_b, bs);
  cudaMalloc(&d_vec_a, bs);
  cudaMalloc(&d_c, sizeof(mytype));
// fill host vectors a and b
  for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
  {
    h_vec_a[i] = i+1;//__mat_rand();
    h_vec_b[i] = i+1;//__mat_rand();
  }
  h_c[0] = 0;
  cudaMemcpy(d_vec_a, h_vec_a, bs, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_vec_b, h_vec_b, bs, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_c, h_c, sizeof(mytype), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  dot(d_vec_a, d_vec_b, n, d_c);
  cudaMemcpy(h_c, d_c, sizeof(mytype), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  mytype test_val = 0;
  for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
    test_val += h_vec_a[i] * h_vec_b[i];
  printf("GPU result: %f, CPU result: %f\n", h_c[0], test_val);

}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t372 t372.cu
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
$ cuda-memcheck ./t372
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
GPU result: 2865411584.000000, CPU result: 2865411072.000000
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

The numerical difference in the last 3 digits is due to the limits of `float`, not due to any error in the code.  If you change your initialization to initialize each vector to all 1, for example, you will get an exact result in this case.

Again, for performance reasons, there are a number of criticisms that could be levelled against your code.  If you want a fast dot product I suggest using [CUBLAS](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-dot).

Comment: I am learning the basics of CUDA and programming GPUs for General-purpose Computing. But, how will it be if I use `__threadfence()`  after the `if(x==0) c[0] = 0.0;` line?

Comment: Thanks Robert. Also, I think it would be then best to initialize the sum =0.0 in the `void dot(...)` function only. Right?

Comment: threadfence doesn't enforce order of thread execution . And yes you can initialize c wherever you like as long as it is before the kernel call